# Join between two fact tables (F4801 & F4111)

Tags: sql, oracle, jde

We are working on JDE for our MRP.
There is F4801, that contains every order > one row for each order
And there is F4111, which contains every booking for every item and order.
There are several booking types like

- Correction
- Entry in Inventory
- Samples
- ...

The F4801 contains the column [Started Quantity].
Now I have to compare this column for each order with all "Entry in Inventory" bookings from F4111.
For this purpose I would like to extract all data from F4801 since 01.01.2019. But how?

```
SELECT
F4801.WADOCO "Order",
F4801.WAUORG "Started Quantity"
FROM
    Pool.DB_JDE_PROD F4801
```

I guess then I need a join to get all bookings (type 'TT') from F4111 for each order of 4801, right?
But how?
This is my actual SQL:

```
SELECT
    ILDOC  "Order",
    ILDCT  "Booking Type",
    ILTRQT "Quantity"
FROM 
        Pool.DB_JDE_PROD F4111
WHERE   ILDCT = 'TT'
```

In the end, I need a SQL for the F4801 and one for the F4111. I would like to compare them in excel.

Comment: For those that don't know JDEinternal order structures, the schema of the tables would be helpful to say the least. Plus some sample data, and desired output.

Comment: JDE is Oracle's JD Edwards ?? Because it is not clear in your question

Comment: Yes, it's Oracle's JD Edwards